# change rgb values of a point in opengles

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

i want to make gray scale filter on runtime i succeed to make it by this code

```
NSString *const kGPUImageLuminanceFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
  precision highp float;

   varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

    uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

    const highp vec3 W = vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
   void main()
  {     
   float luminance = dot(texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgb, W);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(luminance), 1.0);
  }
 );
```

what i want now is to access the rgb values of each point and apply on it my algorithm  then change the point rgb values based on my algorithm

my question in other word

i want to access the rgb values of a point and set the rgb values of the same point

Comment: Given that you pulled this fragment shader from my GPUImage framework, I'd highly recommend looking at the other fragment shaders contained within the various filters there. They show many ways of manipulating color information, and should be good examples to work from when developing your own fragment shader.

Comment: if you now the name of class which make some thing like what i want  
 
i just make simple if statement for some rgb values whose R value is less than 120 to apply on it gray scale filter only @BradLarson

Comment: No, I don't have anything that does precisely that, so you're going to need to write your own custom filter. Like I said, take some time and read through the many, many example filters to learn how to do this yourself. You'll be better off for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec3 pixel =  texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgb;
 float red = pixel.r;
 float green = pixel.g;
 float blue = pixel.b;


    .
    . manipulate the values as needed
    .

    gl_FragColor = vec4(red, green, blue, 1.0);
```

OR this to maintain the alpha of the original pixel:

```
vec4 pixel =  texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgba;
.
.
.

    gl_FragColor = vec4(red, green, blue, pixel.a);
```

Comment: I really wouldn't do three separate texture reads for the individual components, but one read into a vec3 or vec4 for a single color.

Comment: is this code access each rgb values of a point individually ??

Comment: Yes.  The float variables red, green, blue will contain the individual colors.

Comment: i just make what you say but it crashes

NSString *const kGPUImageLuminanceFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
precision highp float;
 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
highp vec3 W=vec3(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
 
void main()
 {       
 vec3 pixel=texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgb;
 float red=pixel.r;   
float green=pixel.g;   
float blue=pixel.b  
 if(r>120)  
{       
gl_FragColor = vec4(red,green,blue, 1.0);  
 }    
 else  
 {     
 float luminance = dot(pixel, W);  
   gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(luminance), 1.0); 
 }
 }
);

Comment: i just make simple if statement for some rgb values whose R value is less than 120 to apply on it gray scale filter only

Comment: colors are all normalized from 0.0 to 1.0.  For 120, use 120/256: if (r > 0.46875) {}.  Check your console/debug logs to help with app crash.

Comment: i think this doesn't make the app to crash because 
it will not enter this condition ever that all 
so why it crashes 

and by the way the console log doesn't appear to me to seems to be a bug that put me in a big trouble @CSmith

Comment: @khaled - The reason why that crashes is that GLSL does not do automatic conversion from integers to floating point values, so you're comparing and integer to a float in that if() statement. You'll see the compiler complain about this in the console. As he says, convert this to the normalized 0.0 - 1.0 range.

Comment: @BradLarson 
can you tell me how can i Set the flash light (on, off ,auto ) in  GPUImage framework,

Answer (score 0):

If by point you mean pixel, then I think what you are looking for is a framebuffer object (FBO). It will allow you to render a scene to an image, which then you can feed back into a shader to do whatever you want to it, then you can render that as the final output.